# Pandas Dataframe loading data that was deleted from Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, formatting

I've edited an excel file and am now trying to read it df = pd.read_excel('filename') into a dataframe. The original data is showing up in the data frame but not in the excel file. I have cleared the formatting in excel accross the entire workbook, and copy and pasted it into new tabs.

As it's seen in excel:
[There are two columns, one labeled keys, the other values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lf8rc.png)

As it's seen in the data frame:
[There are 8 columns with their original names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1lLI.png)

Update: I've opened a new excel workbook and copied all data into the new workbook and it seems to be loading the new data now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Restart kernel before running the code again.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that between each attempt.

Comment: even with Restart & Clear Output does not change it? When you completely reset the kernel, all the changes made into the same file uploads again so it should remove the value

Comment: Yes, this was an excel issue. I copied the data and pasted into a new workbook and the changes were reflected in the data frame.